# Attention test for edits

Tags: discussion, review-audit

Just now, I received a request to approve an edit, but it looked really weird. So I chose "reject and edit", and got "Congratulations! This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You passed.  Next"
Congrats, too. You may test your students, but I'm not one of them. Wait for "Next", if you're Methusalem.
Well, that didn't sound like a question until now, but what do *you* think, am I overly sensitive, seeing it like that?

Comment: *grin* OK, downvotes are easier than arguments, especially since downvoting questions doesn't cost you reputation, but: what are you trying to prove?

Comment: This sounds like the review test which has been around since 2013. At that moment, it is so annoying that I completely stop participating in the review process. I don't know whether it has tuned down the wordings or not. In any event, if you disagree with something, you can just walk away from that particular part of math.SE. There are more than one ways to contribute.

Comment: downvote on meta doesn't cost any reputation, it simply mean someone is disagreeing with you (for whatever reason).

Comment: @achille hui Thanks for confirming my feelings. Of course, I'm here to contribute (much like you, I guess), but you're absolutely correct, there are other ways, less susceptible to test-happy professors..

Comment: @ProfessorVector I think this complaint errs on the side of being too pedantic

Comment: @mrnovice That may well be, but as long people prove my point by downvoting without being able to argue, I can't be totally wrong. Let me quote the rules: "Everyone here is volunteering, and no one responds well to demands for help." Well, I would, but... is it really demanding too much that I should be treated like a grown-up, then?

Comment: What exactly is your problem with the test?

Comment: @ProfessorVector You seem to be very hostile,I don't know what this is about and I don't want to insinuate what it is,if you're asking for discussion please explain what do you want to discuss.

Comment: "If what I wrote there isn't clear enough, feel free to ask." Didn't @kingW3 do just that?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I didn't get an answer,is your answer no I won't clarify what I mean? If it is it really contradicts the feel free to ask as I already asked twice.

Comment: If you feel you're "above" tolerating some of MSE's protocols, you can leave the site altogether.  Oh, and to answer your only question, I wouldn't describe you as "oversensitive", but rather as having too much hubris.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I've voted to close because I can't see what question is being raised.  Audits of the review queues have been discussed here and on Meta.SE about as long as they've been implemented (which is about as long as SE has been here).  So please take this as constructive feedback and consider if literally you meant to ask "am I overly sensitive, seeing it like that?"

Answer (score 11):

You are not alone in getting a bit irritate by these tests, and the wording chosen by SE is typically to the more playful side, which does not go over well with everybody.

However, there is some point in having such tests, as it offers at least something of defense against users blindly and irresponsibly clicking through.

I prefer the occasional test, even it may feel a bit silly, over more bad edits getting approved.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't put that precisely enough: I don't have to wait for approval, I edit (or approve). But I didn't get the reputation needed for that out of nothing. So would it be fair to expect that at least the wording (cited above, literally) could be toned down a little bit? I mean "be nice" shouldn't be reserved for users. I do know about the responsibility. And rest assured, I won't approve a bad edit, @quid.

Comment: I am not sure why you believe that I am talking about anything but tests encountered while doing reviews (of edits). Somewhat tangentially, yet not completely, I am wondering is the "Next" actually part of the explanatory text or is it just what the button you are supposed to press says? Further, I do not see what is not nice about the text. It informs you that you passed and even congratulates you. Alright, one could take it as ironic or demeaning to be congratulated for this minimal achievement, but why be so negative.

Comment: Sorry, but "I do not see" is an argument better reserved for your oculist. I think the condescending "you passed" is the main obstacle, most people I know are glad they left _that_ behind. Even if those tests are necessary, I could think of several versions to word that in a moderately civil manner.

Comment: Have left what behind? Passing tests? If you are so aghast of this context,  maybe you should reconsider your user-name. :-)

Comment: It is an empirically established fact that  users that "did something to deserve that reputation" still might approve poor edits. Thus, these tests are in place.

Comment: Then I do not understand the relevance of "people getting the reputation for approving edits did something to deserve that reputation."

Comment: (Bad edits will always be approved. You probably want to say that "over bad edits getting approved more often", or something like that...)

Comment: @Asaf yes, yes. But I sense some ambiguity in "Bad edits will always be approved." too? ;-)

Comment: @ProfessorVector Given the language you've used in this comment thread, I find it extremely ironic that you complain about the site test notices being condescending.